# Safari Parental Controls Whitelist Issue Mac

Tags: safari, osx-elcapitan, whitelist, parental-control

I am attempting to turn a computer into a kiosk for a school library. I am currently working with MacOS El Capitan 10.11.6, this computer is unable to run any newer versions of MacOS due to age.

I am attempting to use parental controls to make Safari only allow a managed user to access the website https://guhsd.follettdestiny.com/ however, while it does allow access to the main page, the parental controls are preventing the managed user from getting to the respective search page for each of the listed schools on that main page, said pages can be reached from the links in the box labeled "High Schools" at the center of the page.

I have tried the "Allow access to only these websites" and "Try to limit access to adult websites automatically" settings for web restriction, however it only whitelists the page with the list of schools and prevents access to each school's respective library search page.

Curiously, when trying the “Try to limit access to adult websites automatically” setting, I only added that main address and the parental controls restricted access to any pages that the main page redirected to, but didn’t prevent access to things like google.com. If anyone can explain why this may have occurred, that information would be appreciated.

The goal is to get safari to only allow the managed user to have access to the web address listed above and all the web pages that share that domain.

I would prefer to not have each individual page added to the bookmarks bar, as that would be visually disliked and as far as I have tested, it wouldn’t work anyway.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated and if this won’t work in safari, I’m willing to consider any suggested browsers instead should you offer instructions on how to achieve this goal with that browser.